# Selecting text code visualstudio with hot key

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed code visualstudio  1.54.1 and having some line of code
if cursor is located on string

```
   $adImageItemImgProps = AdImage::readAdImageProps($adImageItem->ad_id, $adImageItem->image, true);
```

inside of readAdImageProps method name, but when no chars selected and clicking hot key
all readAdImageProps method name is selected
and next clicking hot key
AdImage::readAdImageProps is selected.
and so on...

In similar way in PhpStorm work hot keys Ctrl+W...

**MODIFIED :**
I manually added proposed key lines in /home/username/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json
and see in the file : https://prnt.sc/10lc240
I restarted code visualstudio and "ctrl+shift+alt+w" and this function works in not way I expect.
Say I have in control php file with no test selected : https://prnt.sc/10lc53f

When I click  "ctrl+shift+alt+w" - it works as I expect only for the first time : https://prnt.sc/10lc77h
But not next time when I clcik trhis hot key : https://prnt.sc/10lc7w0  and https://prnt.sc/10lc8xr
Is something wrong in my config ?

Thanks!

Comment: You ASK to extent selection with the parent scope `AAA::`, Apparently Ctrl+W in PHPStorm does more than that. If you don't describe what you expect I can't propose a solution. If you look closely to the screenshots the selection is extended to the next parent scope backwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by)

It is a 2 phase solution.

1. If no selection yet use the command `editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch` to select the word under the cursor
2. If selection then extend at the begin to the next parent scope

Ad this to your `keybindings.json` file

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+w",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection",
    "command": "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+w",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection",
    "command": "selectby.regex",
    "args": {
      "backward": "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+::",
      "backwardInclude": true
    }
  }
```

**Edit**

I removed the `forward` search because it was taken care of by the `no-selection` case.

Comment: Thanks, Could you please explain how/where have I to fill p2?

Comment: @mstdmstd It is the same shortcut key but different commands based on the `where`

Comment: I ask is it some config file? Can I edit manually or in VC studio tols?

Comment: @mstdmstd this goes in the `keybindings.json` file

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED  block